# If one of the focii of ellipse is moved to infinity, then how it becomes a parabola?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Eccentricity of Parabola is 1.
Eccentricity of ellipse is <1.
    i.e. FP / PM = 1 for parabola.
     Then how an ellipse will become a parabola if F1P / PM =e<1 if F1 is any one of its focus?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres